# Directory Apache server permissions

Tags: apache, permissions, directory

The function "is_writeable" of php it returns false, then the directory that im proving have the next permissions 755 owner and the root group. To make it run i put chown www-data -R /var/www/myweb. Doing that it works, but i change the owner from root to apache (www-data). My question is if that form of solve it it's correct or not. I'm making a big hole security or it's correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing owner from `root` to `www-data` is ok. I would be careful of making everything writable though (with `-R`). You should probably only make the bare minimum writable. You might want to run `chown www-data:www-data` to change both owner and group.